# Bash grep - find exact wording in the line

Tags: bash, shell, unix, scripting

I have a question using grep / egrep in bash

Imagine I have the following lines in the file:

```
Good day
Hello World 23 a
Hi Hello World
Hello World
sdHello World
Hello Worldsss
```

The problem is to find the line with exact match of string: "Hello World"

I tried to use

```
grep -n "^Hello World$" file.txt
```

but it doesn't work giving an empty result

Comment: This works fine for me - are you sure you're running what you posted above?

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to look for exact matches, rather than matching a regular expression, use `-F` to specify that you're searching for a fixed string.

And to make it match the whole line instead of a substring, use `-x`.

```
grep -n -F -x "Hello World" file.txt
```

But your `^Hello World$` regexp should have worked. If it's not matching,then the file may not contain what you think it does. One possibility is that it contains Windows `CRLF` newlines instead of Unix `LF` newlines. Use `dos2unix file.txt` to fix it.

Comment: thanks a lot! the problem was solved with {dos2unix file.txt}